# How to make a REST call to an Azure Queue

Tags: rest, azure, c#-4.0, azure-queues

I am able to make a C# library call to a queue using the SDK. However I am unable to make a REST call to the queue.

How shall I proceed? Any code sample will be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far and what are the issues you're running into. I'm sure that if you do a proper search you will find lots of code samples in C# where REST API is being consumed instead of using .Net SDK.

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried to do some search, but I am not able to find the ones fitting my requirement.I am very new to azure.Any sample code link will be appreciated

Comment: Though a bit old but take a look here: https://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com. This should give you an idea about how to proceed.

Comment: we have shared you some samples, are you able to operate Azure queue via Rest API now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am able to make a c# library call to a queue using SDK. However i am unable to make a Rest Call to the queue. How shall i proceed and Any code sample will be appreciated.

Firstly, [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/operations-on-queues) lists the REST operations for working with message queues  that Azure Storage provides, please check the link to get detailed informations.

Secondly, here is a sample request to [create a queue under the given account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/create-queue4), you could construct your request like this.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
"https://{0}.queue.core.windows.net/{1}",
StorageAccount, queuename));

req.Method = "PUT";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader);
req.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", mxdate);
req.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);
req.ContentLength = 0;
```

and please refer to the following code and [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services) to construct the signature string for generating **AuthorizationHeader**.

```
string canonicalizedHeaders = string.Format(
    "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
    mxdate,
    storageServiceVersion);

string canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", StorageAccount, queuename);

string stringToSign = string.Format(
"{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}",
requestMethod,
canonicalizedHeaders,
canonicalizedResource);
```

the request looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the official documentation:

```
Request:  
POST https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/messages?visibilitytimeout=30&timeout=30 HTTP/1.1  

Headers:  
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18  
x-ms-date: Tue, 30 Aug 2011 01:03:21 GMT  
Authorization: SharedKey myaccount:sr8rIheJmCd6npMSx7DfAY3L//V3uWvSXOzUBCV9wnk=  
Content-Length: 100  

Body:  
<QueueMessage>  
<MessageText>PHNhbXBsZT5zYW1wbGUgbWVzc2FnZTwvc2FtcGxlPg==</MessageText>  
</QueueMessage>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-message